# SQL Server : Sum of DateDiff From Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a couple tables structured similar to this:

- `Run ([RunID], [PlayerID], [Score])`
- `Jump ([ID], [RunID], [Time], [Type])`

There are 4 "types" of time 2 "up" and 2 "down".

I need to get the time between an "up" and an "down" on a given run.

Basically, during a "run" when a "jump" is made, I record an up time, and a down is recorded on a corresponding landing (only one pair per run). At the end of the "run" I need to display the total time "in air", as well as time per jump. I was thinking the best way to do this would be to dump into a temp table with the following structure:

```
@tempJump ([RunID], [TimeUp], [TimeDown])
```

Then I would have all the needed info to calculate and populate the necessary fields.

So far I have tried everything from simple selects/joins to the dreaded cursors, but I am having trouble matching the "ups" to the corresponding "downs" and putting them in the temp table with the correct "run".

Any ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

Sample schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE Run
    ([RunID] int, [PlayerID] int, [Score] int)
;

INSERT INTO Run
    ([RunID], [PlayerID], [Score])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1000),
    (2, 1, 1100),
    (3, 1, 800),
    (4, 2, 1500),
    (5, 1, 900)
;

CREATE TABLE Jump
    ([JumpID] int, [RunID] int, [Time] datetime, [Type] int)
;

INSERT INTO Jump
    ([JumpID], [RunID], [Time], [Type])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2013-08-13 18:00:04', 1),
    (2, 1, '2013-08-13 18:00:10', 2),
    (3, 2, '2013-08-13 18:02:15', 1),
    (4, 2, '2013-08-13 18:02:45', 4),
    (5, 3, '2013-08-13 18:04:20', 3),
    (6, 3, '2013-08-13 18:05:01', 2),
    (7, 4, '2013-08-13 18:10:12', 3),
    (8, 4, '2013-08-13 18:11:25', 4),
    (9, 5, '2013-08-13 18:15:00', 1),
    (10, 5, '2013-08-13 18:25:20', 4)
;

CREATE TABLE JumpType
    ([TypeID] int, [Description] varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO JumpType
    ([TypeID], [Description])
VALUES
    (1, 'UpPlatform'),
    (2, 'DownPlatform'),
    (3, 'UpBoost'),
    (4, 'DownBoost')
;
```

Expected output of the query would be a temp table similar to:

```
RunID        PlayerID          TimeUp                     TimeDown
 1              1          '2013-08-13 18:00:04'       2013-08-13 18:00:10
```

Comment: When asking query related questions, especially when you don't provide your version of the query, please at least help those who want to help you and provide your table(s) schema, sample data, and desired output based on it. Better yet spend one minute and create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your sample data.

Comment: @peterm Thank you for the pointers. I have edited the post to, hopefully, include the information you requested. If not, let me know, and I will revise it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question this will work. I've joined on your *jump type* table rather than assuming the id's (personally I think its a bad idea to assume id's eg assume 1 and 3 are the *up* type)

Also I've used an *inner* join to get the corresponding down jump - **I am assuming that if the jumper goes up he will come down ;)**

```
select
    r.RunID,
    r.PlayerID,
    TimeUp = uj.[Time],
    TimeDown = dj.[Time],
    TimeDifference = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, uj.Time, dj.Time)
from @Run r
inner join @Jump uj on uj.RunID = r.RunID
inner join @JumpType ut on ut.TypeID = uj.[Type] 
inner join @Jump dj on dj.RunID = uj.RunID
inner join @JumpType dt on dt.TypeID = dj.[Type]
where ut.[Description] like '%Up%'
and dt.[Description] like '%Down%'
```

**ORIGINAL - before you showed us your schema**

Heres what I cam up with

The type table indicate if its an up or down time with the `IsUpElseAssumeIsDown` field

```
declare @TimeType table (Id int, Name nvarchar(20), IsUpElseAssumeIsDown bit)

insert into @TimeType (Id, Name, IsUpElseAssumeIsDown) values 
(1, '1st Up Type', 1), (2, '1st Down Type', 0),
(3, '2st Up Type', 1), (4, '2st Down Type', 0)
```

Now a set up jumps to test with

```
declare @Jump table ([ID] int, [RunID] int, [Time] time, [Type] int)

insert into @Jump ([ID], [RunID], [Time], [Type]) values
(1, 1, '10:00:05.000', 1), (2, 1, '10:00:15.000', 2),
(3, 2, '10:00:15.000', 3), (4, 2, '10:00:25.100', 4),
(5, 3, '10:00:25.000', 1), (6, 3, '10:00:35.200', 4),
(7, 4, '10:00:35.000', 3), (8, 4, '10:00:45.300', 4),
(9, 5, '10:00:45.000', 1), -- no down time for 1st up type 
(10, 6, '10:00:55.000', 3) -- no down time for 2nd up type
```

Finally a query to get our results

```
-- @tempJump ([RunID], [TimeUp], [TimeDown])

;with UpJump
as
(
    select j.RunID, j.[Time]
    from @Jump j
    inner join @TimeType t on t.Id = j.[Type] 
    where t.IsUpElseAssumeIsDown = 1
)
,DownJump
as
(
    select j.RunID, j.[Time]
    from @Jump j
    inner join @TimeType t on t.Id = j.[Type] 
    where t.IsUpElseAssumeIsDown = 0
)
select 
    u.RunID, 
    TimeUp = u.[Time],
    TimeDown = d.[Time],
    TimeDifference = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, u.Time, d.Time) 
from UpJump u
inner join DownJump d on d.RunID = u.RunID
```

Results in this

```
RunID   TimeUp              TimeDown            TimeDifference
1       10:00:05.0000000    10:00:15.0000000    10000
2       10:00:15.0000000    10:00:25.1000000    10100
3       10:00:25.0000000    10:00:35.2000000    10200
4       10:00:35.0000000    10:00:45.3000000    10300
```

I've used cte's to make the query more readable but you could have written like this (with just joins)

```
select 
    uj.RunID, 
    TimeUp = uj.[Time],
    TimeDown = dj.[Time],
    TimeDifference = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, uj.Time, dj.Time)
from @Jump uj
inner join @TimeType ut on ut.Id = uj.[Type] 
inner join @Jump dj on dj.RunID = uj.RunID
inner join @TimeType dt on dt.Id = dj.[Type]
where ut.IsUpElseAssumeIsDown = 1 
and dt.IsUpElseAssumeIsDown = 0
```

Comment: This is great.... But I didn't catch the fact that RunID, PlayerID, JumpID are not Ints, they are GUIDs. Will this still work? I really apologize for the oversight, but after going at this for 14 hours straight I'm lucky to be typing right honestly at this point lol

Comment: Yes the query is the same. But for guids you'd need to use the `uniqueidentifier` data type instead of an `int`.

Comment: PS, if you're able to i'd suggest amending the JumpType table to make it explicit which rows represent up types and which are down types eg add a bit column `IsUpElseAssumeIsDown` like my original answer has shown...

Comment: Ok, then I must have gotten the schema wrong I guess. All of the "Ups" are coming up correctly, but the "Downs" are all coming up as the same field. I will work with this some more tomorrow after I catch a couple hours of sleep and check back.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    r.RunID, r.PlayerID, ju.Time as TimeUp, jd.Time as TimeDown
from Run as R 
    left outer join Jump as ju on ju.RunID = r.RunID and ju.[Type] in (1, 3)
    left outer join Jump as jd on jd.RunID = r.RunID and jd.[Type] in (2, 4)
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d565/17)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.RunID, up.Time, down.Time, DATEDIFF(millisecond, up.Time, down.Time) as miliseconds
     FROM Run r 
LEFT JOIN Jump up   ON r.RunID = up.RunID   AND (up.Type   = 1 OR up.Type = 3)
LEFT JOIN Jump down ON r.RunID = down.RunID AND (down.Type = 2 OR down.Type = 4)
WHERE up.JumpID IS NOT NULL AND down.JumpID IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d565/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
select J.RunID,Max(R.PlayerID) as PlayerID,min(J.Time) as TimeUP,max(J.time) as TimeDown
from Run R
inner join Jump J on R.RunID=J.RunID
inner join JumpType JT on J.Type=JT.TypeID
where JT.Description in ('UpPlatform','DownPlatform')
or JT.Description in ('UpPlatform','DownPlatform')
group by J.RunID
having COUNT(J.RunID)>1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab1e2/1)**

Comment: @bullrider Please have a look to my answer.